# Spring Data Hibernate: N+1 problem and pagination

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, pagination

TL;DR -- I cannot find a way to solve the N+1 problem while doing pagination at the same time.

My Entities:

```
@Entity
public class Invoice {

    @Id
    @JsonView(InvoiceView.ShortView.class)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

// other stuff

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = InvoiceItem.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "invoice")
    private List<InvoiceItem> items;
}

@Entity
public class InvoiceItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

// other stuff
}
```

My repository:

```
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"vendor","items"})
    @Query(value = "select i from Invoice i where i.status=:status")
    Page<Invoice> getInvoicesWithItemsByStatus(@Param("status") Status status, Pageable pageSpec);
```

or

```
        @Query(value = "select i from Invoice i join fetch i.items join fetch i.vendor where i.status=:status",
            countQuery = "select count(i) from Invoice i where i.status=:status")
    Page<Invoice> getInvoicesWithItemsByStatus(@Param("status") Status status, Pageable pageSpec);
```

Both of these produce this Hibernate warning:

```
HHH000104: firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!
```

and they do just that: fetch everything and give back the page requested. Every time a new page is requested, naturally.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem and how to solve it is described in this article by Vlad Mihalcea

https://vladmihalcea.com/fix-hibernate-hhh000104-entity-fetch-pagination-warning-message/

Basically, you would need to write a native query.

Comment: that's not a solution. it just confirms it cannot be done.

Comment: Thats the correct link https://vladmihalcea.com/fix-hibernate-hhh000104-entity-fetch-pagination-warning-message/ (it's on the intro of the article I linked). You will need to write a native query

Comment: Thanks mate -- there are any number of workarounds for this problem, that do not involve the use of a framework (or involve the use of __another__ one :) ) -- I was just trying to see if the JPA way of doing it is actually usable. Apparently it's not.